# Regular Expressions contains in bigquery example

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to write regular expressions in bigquery to match the following two under title column: I want to get exactly these two. There are some other values containing 3 Percent, but I want to get only these two.

WBC - SAV - 3 Percent Q4 FY20

Canstar - canstar.com.au - AFF: Table Listing - Cost per click - National - 1x1 - 3 percent Savings

My code is:

WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(title, '(?i) 3 Percent')
THEN '3% PF'

I am not getting the correct output. Can anyone please assist.

Comment: looks good to me. so, what is expected correct output here? please clarify

Comment: @ Mikhali, I want to match exactly these two. I am getting some others which has 3 percent. Do I need to include full name to get exactly these two.

Comment: show those "some others" so we see the issue

Comment: WBC - SAV - 3 Percent cards. I would like to discard it.

Comment: please update your question with clear logic that you have in mind  - so we will be able to help :o)

Comment: @ Mikhali, I've updated the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are some other values containing 3 Percent, but I want to get only these two.

So, in this case you don't need regular expression and rather use below

```
WHEN title IN (
  'WBC - SAV - 3 Percent Q4 FY20', 
  'Canstar - canstar.com.au - AFF: Table Listing - Cost per click - National - 1x1 - 3 percent Savings'
) THEN '3% PF'
```